# Sequelize. Find where hasMany associations count?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have 2 models. First model hasMany second.

I need to findAll 1 model instances where associated seconds count more than 10 for example.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: use aggregate functions.

```js
  let res = await Second.findAll({
    attributes: ['firstId', [sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('first_id')), 'count']],
    having: sequelize.literal(`count(*) > 10`),
    group: ['Second.first_id'],
    raw: true,
  });
```